# FTP based approach for moving data

Tags: .net, architecture, ftp

So, we have application that runs it own process at some point in time and produces information, now this information is basically consumed by several other applications. The current approach to the solution is for this source application to create a file and send it to each and every consumer through FTP. The data sent over would be around 2-3 million records.
I think FTP is an old technology for this purpose and that there are better ways of solving this problem.
Any thoughts?

Regards,
Nairooz

Comment: So FTP is old but if you want to move files it is pretty efficient.  You don't provide enough information about how that data is processed to make recommendations.

Comment: Could you put the file on a common share and have the clients access it directly? How about putting it on an FTP site and telling the clients it's there so that they can get it (i.e. notify and pull, rather than push)? Without more information about the network topology and other system specific things, there's no way to give you a reasonable answer.

Comment: ftp/sftp is still used widely and one of the best ways to transfer large files. Instead of sending the data over ftp to several consumer you can have the consumers pull it, but it all depends on the use case and the contract with the consumer. Now, more information is required to see the problems with the current approach or to suggest other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Socket file transfer? Have a timer set to check for a version number or checksum of the data to see if it have been updated and then initiate a transfer if the data is newer than the current set it has.

You can use a dynamic DNS service (for free/very cheap) if you don't have static IPs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ew28f56.aspx